# GeoIPCity.dat file where do I find it?

Tags: geoip

I have a file GeoIPCity.day on one of my sites. The original developer told me it was a free file from maxmind.com and I should update it every month. I have looked on maxmind.com and haven't been able to find a file with the exact same name. Any idea what file I should used as the update? Here are the list of files I was able to find on the website: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/#Downloads

Answer (score 4):

The Legacy "dat" format DBs are discontinued:

https://support.maxmind.com/geolite-legacy-discontinuation-notice/

Answer (score 3):

Free version of the GEO IP City was rename from GeoIPCity.dat TO GeoLiteCity.dat.

## Download the data. This should work on CentOS 7/7.1

`wget -N http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz -O /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz && gunzip --force /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz`

## this maintenance a backward compatible version

`ln -s /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat`

Comment: This whole naming change caused a lot of trouble for people.

Comment: Domain does not exist in 2022 anymore

Answer (score 3):

The old files can be download from the following: https://mirrors-cdn.liferay.com/geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/

A copy of the file "GeoLiteCity.dat" is also available from github at the following url:

https://github.com/mbcc2006/GeoLiteCity-data

Click on Code button then download

[image: GeoLiteCity.dat]